# Scalar field equation of state

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology

Consider a scalar field $(+,-,-,-)$ with the following Lagrangian density
$$\mathscr{L} = \frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi + V\,.$$
The associated stress energy tensor is
$$T_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu\phi\partial_\nu\phi -g_{\mu\nu}\left(\frac{1}{2}\partial^\alpha\phi\partial_\alpha\phi - V\right)\,.$$
Comparing this to the stress energy tensor of a perfect fluid
$$T_{\mu\nu} = (\rho + P)u_\mu u_\nu - Pg_{\mu\nu}\,,$$
yields the following relationship
$$u = \frac{\partial_\mu\phi}{\sqrt{\partial_\alpha\phi\partial^\alpha\phi}}\,,\hspace{1cm} \rho = \partial_\alpha\phi\partial^\alpha\phi + V\,,\hspace{1cm} P = \partial_\alpha\phi\partial^\alpha\phi - V\,.$$
Therefore, the cosmological equation of state is
$$w\equiv\frac{P}{\rho} = \frac{\partial_\alpha\phi\partial^\alpha\phi - V}{\partial_\alpha\phi\partial^\alpha\phi + V}\,.$$
The equipartition theorem for a harmonic oscillator implies that a cold gas of non-interacting matter will have $\langle{\partial_\alpha\phi\partial^\alpha\phi}\rangle = \langle V\rangle$, hence CDM has $w = 0$. In other words, it is a pressureless fluid, as expected.

Radiation, on the other hand, is equivalent to a gas of relativistic particles. My intuition tells me that this means I can neglect the rest mass of the particle, and therefore (assuming self interactions can be neglected) we have $w = 1$. However, it is well known that radiation has the equation of state $w = 1/3$. Where has my reasoning gone wrong?